# execute Fluture task with Sancuary Either

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, sanctuary, fluture

I have a pipe like this

```
const asyncFn = (x) => {
    return Future.tryP(() => Promise.resolve(x + ' str2'))
};

const pipeResult = S.pipe([
    x => S.Right(x + " str1"), // some validation function
    S.map(asyncFn),
])("X");

pipeResult.fork(console.error, console.log);
```

I want to do some async operation in `asyncFn`.
The problem is when I have `Right` as input I can fork it anymore.

When I log the `pipeResult` I see this:

```
Right (tryP(() => Promise.resolve(x + ' str2')))
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Either a b` and `Future a b` are both capable of expressing failure/success. When working with asynchronous computations it is usually better to use `Future a b` rather than `Future a (Either b c)`. The simpler, flatter type requires less mapping: `S.map (f)` rather than `S.map (S.map (f))`. Another advantage is that the error value is always in the same place, whereas with `Future a (Either b c)` both `a` and `b` represent failed computations.

We may, though, already have a validation function that returns an either. For example:

```
//    validateEmail :: String -> Either String String
const validateEmail = s =>
  s.includes ('@') ? S.Right (S.trim (s)) : S.Left ('Invalid email address');
```

If we have a value `fut` of type `Future String String`, how do we validate the email address `fut` may contain? The first thing to try is always `S.map`:

```
S.map (validateEmail) (fut) :: Future String (Either String String)
```

It would be nice to avoid this nesting. In order to do so, we first need to define a function from `Either a b` to `Future a b`:

```
//    eitherToFuture :: Either a b -> Future a b
const eitherToFuture = S.either (Future.reject) (Future.resolve);
```

We can now transform an either-returning function into a future-returning function:

```
S.compose (eitherToFuture) (validateEmail) :: String -> Future String String
```

Let's revisit our use of `S.map`:

```
S.map (S.compose (eitherToFuture) (validateEmail)) (fut) :: Future String (Future String String)
```

We still have nesting, but now the inner and outer types are both `Future String _`. This means we can replace `S.map` with `S.chain` to avoid introducing nesting:

```
S.chain (S.compose (eitherToFuture) (validateEmail)) (fut) :: Future String String
```

Comment: `eitherToFuture` helper function was what I looking for. thanks